# Xcodebuild throws error in new Xcode-8 Beta version

Tags: xcodebuild, ios-provisioning, xcode8, code-signing-entitlements, xcode8-beta2

I get this error Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'", whenever i try building my app from command line using xcodebuild. The same command works fine with previous versions of Xcode. In general "xcodebuild command" works in previous versions of xcode but not from Xcode 8 (Currently beta version).

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign in your Apple Credentials in Xcode->Preferences->Accounts. Once that is done, select target, check the section Signing, select the team, it will create a provisioning profile automatically. Go to Build Settings->Signing section, Choose Provisioning Profile as "Automatic" and Code Signing Identity as "iOS Developer". Build and Run.

[Signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhQGg.png)

[Apple Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqj1Y.png)

Comment: We release builds from central infrastructure, here we dont open developers source code at all to modify the above  mentioned changes. All i want is xcodebuild command to work on latest xcode 8 beta version